# Excel slicer multi-select functionality turns off when workbook is closed?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers, vba

I have a workbook that contains a report with tables and slicers.

Currently, when the user opens the workbook, they must manually click the "multi-select" option on the slicer. Is there a way to keep this permanently selected (even when the workbook is closed and re-opened)?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47018410/212869 - doesn't look like it