# Multi-select Excel slicers

Tags: excel, slicers, vba

I would like to set Multi-select to be the default setup of three slicers in a dashboard.

I wrote three (one per slicer) short procedures that look like this:

```
Sub msel() 

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Slicer1")).Select 
 SendKeys "%s" 
 SendKeys "(ESC)" 

End Sub
```

When invoked independently, the procedures work. When I try to invoke the three of them from another Sub, only the last Call works (i.e., only one slicer happens to be in Multi-select mode).

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

*** something like this (see below) has the same effect:

```
Sub All()

Dim sCache As SlicerCache
Dim sl As Slicer

For Each sCache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    For Each sl In sCache.Slicers
        sl.Shape.Select
        SendKeys "%s"
        SendKeys "{ESC}"
    Next sl
Next sCache

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you want to use select? Can't you just loop through sliceritems per slicer?

Comment: @JvdV Right, in fact I am looping to clear the filters and that works fine. What I haven't been able to do is enable the multi-select

Comment: Right, well....you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018410/excel-enable-multi-select-on-slicer-by-default

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for your quick response. I found that Q&A. Interestingly though,  as I mention in my question when I invoke one of the Subs (for one slicer) it works as intended.

Comment: Hm, okay, so what if you don't call three different procedures but loop through these slicers on the Workbook_open event? https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/683y2u/is_there_a_way_to_have_a_slicer_have_multiselect/. I'll be suprised if this works.

Comment: @jeffreyweir that did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect Excel is looping too fast for the SendKeys to have effect. If I add a DoEvents after your second SendKeys it works just fine for me.